# ¿Como solucionar el problema de borde a la hora de calcular las variables de segundo orden de una matriz GLCM de una imagen en R?

Tags: r

He estado intentando calcular las variables de segundo orden de una matriz GLCM de una imagen en R. He intentado con el paquete "GLCM" pero, dependiendo del tamaño de ventana que escoja, el resultado es un raster con las filas y columnas de borde sin valores (NaN). He leído la teoría de como se calcula la GLCM, y en efecto, si se calcula en todas las direcciones, van a resultar NaN en los bordes del raster resultante. Por lo anterior, mi pregunta es ¿hay alguna forma o método para calcular los valores de los píxeles de borde?

Agradezco su ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tendrías que formar parte del equipo de desarrollo del paquete GLCM y corregirlo desde el código fuente.

Este hecho ya fue reportado en [este issue del github de GLCM](https://github.com/azvoleff/glcm/issues/6) desde el 27 de marzo del año pasado y esta abandonado desde entonces según las estadísticas de la página.